# German-to-English translation of a paper by Esselmann

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-german

Do you have any idea how to translate the following paper from Frank Esselmann?

- Frank Esselmann, *[Über die maximale Dimension von Lorentz–Gittern mit coendlicher Spiegelungsgruppe](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jnth.1996.0141),* Journal of Number Theory, Volume 61, Issue 1, November 1996, Pages 103–144.

I didn't find anything good on the Internet. Google trad is quite lame and I tried to fix it by myself but German is pretty hard. Do you have good option to translate this paper? It's quite long: 40 pages.

Comment: Translating 40 pages is a rather time-consuming process. Not to mention that you would probably need somebody knowledgeable of this particular area of research. Have you tried to look whether the results you need are not published in some (English) article which [cites Esselmann's work](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=2120963262340878543) or in some of the books where [this paper is mentioned](https://books.google.com/books?q="Lorentz+Gittern+mit+coendlicher+Spiegelungsgruppe")?

Comment: Yes i tried but i found nothing. Borcherds added in a remark in his thesis, citing the german version. I don't know any english version of the article. Is there a google trad that is special for maths ?

Comment: Start by just translating the theorems. See if you can prove them without reading the paper. If you get stuck translate the passages that seem to be about the points you are stuck on.